# Mix textures in predefined materials

Tags: javascript, three.js

Is there a way to add multiplie texture maps to a material like phong?

I know it's easy to use shadermaterial and pass them as uniforms, than just mix in the shader, but I want to use predefined specularmaps, envmaps etc. and don't want to rewrite everything from scratch.

Comment: If you don't want to extend `MeshPhongMaterial` with a custom `ShaderMaterial`, you can render to a texture first using your mixing shader, and then use the texture as `MeshPhongMaterial.map`.

Comment: @WestLangley Thanks for a helpful hint as usual:) As Im still learning about 3d graphics, can You tell me if this is the proper way to achieve it? Like in this example: view-source:http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_rtt.html . Create an extra scene using the shader on a plane width screen width and height and another texture as a rendertarget, which is later passed to the mainscene?

Comment: Correct. But as you will soon discover, the "full screen quad" has to fill the orthographic camera's frustum. The dimensions, or units, of the frustum and quad have nothing to do with the screen dimensions.

Comment: thanks a lot. Working like a charm! Post Your solution as an answer, so i will checkmark it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to add multiple texture maps to `MeshPhongMaterial` and mix or blend them.

If you don't want to replicate the functionality of `MeshPhongMaterial` with a custom `ShaderMaterial`, you can render to a texture first using your mixing shader, and then use the resulting texture as the `MeshPhongMaterial.map`.

three.js has a render-to-texture example [here](http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_rtt.html).

three.js.r.71

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out the [documentation page for `MeshPhongMaterial`](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Materials/MeshPhongMaterial)?

It supports a number of different textures at the same time, and has some rudimentary support for defining how they are blended.

Comment: yes, i did. What i need is to use multiple color maps. One thing i've found digging through threejs sources is "createMultiMaterialObject" but it would create multiple objects and merge them into a group. What I would like to achieve is to use the same material but with mixed textures from map.